# Bootstrap Two Column Site - Content in Column 1 Increases Margins in Column 2

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

First I would like to introduce myself as I am new to the community and excited to be a part of it.

I'm currently building a two column website using Twitter Bootstrap - a left column taking up the majority of the page as a news section and a right column acting as a side bar. I built panels with media objects under the news section and create a new row for each media object so it will create a running newsfeed though as I begin to add content to the media objects, it increases the margins between elements in the sidebar column. This might have something to do with the grid I'm using but I've hit a bit of a wall on this issue and would greatly appreciate some guidance. So far all the CSS I have been  writing is only controlling the size of a few elements and not the position of anything.

Here is the base for the grid I'm using.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
                  <p id="newsHead">NEWS</p>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="media">
            <a class="media-left">
                <img src="news.png" width="64" height="64">
            </a>
            <div class="media-body">
                <h4 class="media-heading">Content</h4>
                Content for Panel

        </div>
        </div>
              </div>
            </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <p id="instaHead">Element</p>
         <script src="http://snapwidget.com/js/snapwidget.js"></script>

        <iframe id="insta" src="#"
         title="Instagram Widget" class="snapwidget-widget" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0"
         scrolling="yes" style="border:none; overflow:hidden;"></iframe>
            </div>
    </div>

<div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-md-8">
         <div class="panel panel-default">
             <div class="panel-body">
                 <div class="media">
                     <a class="media-left">
                         <img src="news.png" width="64" height="64">
                     </a>
                     <div class="media-body">
                         <h4 class="media-heading">This is a Test</h4>
                         Here is some more text to test this panel!

                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <!-- Youtube Widget -->

        <p id="tubeHead">Element2</p>
        <iframe  id="video" width="300" height="300" src="#"
                frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>  


.thumbnail
{
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
}
#head
{
   margin-bottom: 25px;
}
#instaHead
{
background-color: red;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
width: 300px;
font-family: curves;


}

#tubeHead
 {
   background-color: red;
   color: white;
   font-weight: bold;
   width: 300px;
   font-family: curves;

  }

  #musicHead
 {
   background-color: red;
  color: white;
   font-weight: bold;
   width: 300px;
   font-family: curves;
 }

    #newsHead
   {
     background-color: red;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: curves;
   }
    #LiveHead
    {
   background-color: red;
   color: white;
   font-weight: bold;
   width: 300px;
   font-family: curves;
   }

   .panel-body
  {
    background-color: ghostwhite;
  }
```

So as content is being added to the first media object the margins are increased between the elements Element1 and Element 2 in the col-md-4 columns. Would setting the background as fixed solve this problem? I'm still relatively new to both HTML and CSS so I do appreciate your help in advance.

Here is a fiddle of the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/rkirby/oaw2aphw/1/

Comment: please provide a fiddle to make your issue easier to understand.

Comment: Ah good point. Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/rkirby/oaw2aphw/1/

As you play around with the media-body you will notice the margins start to change. Most of the images are hosted locally so excuse the mess.

Comment: @ProllyGeek Here is the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what happens , when you dont organize your mark up well , you ended up nesting two `row` class divs inside one `row` , however here is the correct markup:

http://jsfiddle.net/oaw2aphw/2/

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Home.css">
</head>
<body>

<!--Start Header -- >

<!-- Start Main Content Area with SideBar -->
<!-- All MD-8 columns contain the Main Content Area -->
<!-- All MD-4 columns contain the Side Bar -->

<div id="MainContent" class="container">
    <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
            <img id="head" src="websiteheader1.jpg"">
            </div>
            <div class="page-header" align="center">

            </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">

        </div>
        </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <p id="newsHead">NEWS</p>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="media">
                <a class="media-left">
                    <img src="news.png" width="64" height="64">
                </a>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h4 class="media-heading">Show on November 22</h4>
                    We're happy to announce we will be preforming with our good friends The Wake of Man November 22nd
                    The Boiler Room, Deep Ellum!

            </div>
            </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p id="instaHead">INSTAGRAM</p>
            <!-- Instagram SnapWidget -->
            <script src="http://snapwidget.com/js/snapwidget.js"></script>

            <iframe id="insta" src="http://snapwidget.com/in/?u=ZXZlbmluZ2Nyb3dkfGlufDEyNXwzfDF8fG5vfDV8bm9uZXxvblN0YXJ0fHllc3x5ZXM=&ve=081114"
             title="Instagram Widget" class="snapwidget-widget" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0"
             scrolling="yes" style="border:none; overflow:hidden;"></iframe>
                </div>
        </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
             <div class="panel panel-default">
                 <div class="panel-body">
                     <div class="media">
                         <a class="media-left">
                             <img src="news.png" width="64" height="64">
                         </a>
                         <div class="media-body">
                             <h4 class="media-heading">This is a Test</h4>
                             Here is some more text to test this panel!

                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <!-- Youtube Widget -->

            <p id="tubeHead">YOUTUBE</p>
            <iframe  id="video" width="300" height="300" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/4WazOnpWYFw?list=UUy_Tglb_2pq4og0iKhI2v9A"
                    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>



</div>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
           <!-- Bandcamp Widget -->
            <p id="musicHead">MUSIC</p>

            <iframe width="300" height="300" scrolling="yes" frameborder="no"
            src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/users/21091800&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>

            </div>
    </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <p id="LiveHead">Featured Photo</p>
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="EClive1.jpg">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>Breakaway Festival</h3>
                        <p>Stephen Jabour rocking out at Breakaway Festival. .</p>
                        <p><a href="https://www.facebook.com/Eveningcrowd/photos/a.483256625105692.1073741827.284765664954790/558289804269040/?type=3&theater"
                        class="btn btn-primary" role="button">See More</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
         </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, though when I open the fiddle and edit the markup the margins in the second column still increase based on the content in the first column. 

Also, do you have any suggestions for keeping more organized markup? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see now my error was due to messy markup and not setting the size of my elements properly. Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: @ReaganKirby sorry i was away couldnt reply , but glad your solved it , anyway i would recommend using sublime text , bracket.io , or https://codeanywhere.net/ , if my answers was correct please choose it as correct answer , good luck :)

Comment: @ProllyGreek lol I didn't mean that sarcastically. I didn't think anyone was going to respond this quickly. I will save yours as the correct answer and thanks for your help!